# dummyjson API response for creating a new product is 200 instead of 201

Tags: json, rest

My problem is:

I'm using dummyjson API (https://dummyjson.com/), and what I'm trying to do is:

> POST > https://dummyjson.com/products/add

I added headers, a JSON body as expected but when I send what I get as `statusCode` is always 200, while it's suppose to be 201. Check my print:

[image: statusCode = 200]

So... Am I doing something wrong? Isn't status code 201 suppose to be there as I'm creating something? I get the same `statusCode` when I try to do another

> POST > https://dummyjson.com/auth/login

This POST is suppose to generate a token and it does but my answer is still 200.

Comment: Does anywhere in the Docs says it's 201. What you're expecting is HTTP standard but it doesn't mean that it will happen in every appplication. People can choose the any status code as they want.